# Query Facebook Graph using FQL by fetching a url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm currently trying to us FQL to find the networks of registered users.

According to the documentation, the url fetched should be something along the lines of:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT affiliations FROM standard_user_info WHERE uid=me()&access_token=tokengoeshere&application_secret=appsecretgoeshere

However, when querying I get Error code 15: The method you are calling must be called with an app secret signed session.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I execute this query by passing my app's access_token (not an access token that associates me with a certain user) and without the app_secret. I get an empty set in response but no error.

Also (just making sure) you will obviously need to URL-escape the query.

Answer (score 1):

This usually works

```
var facebookURL = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query='

var query = 'SELECT bla FROM bla'

var accessToken = 'your access token'

var appToken = '&access_token='+accessToken+'&callback=?'

var url = facebookURL + query + appToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) table instead.